# Looking for Following JavaScript Library That Provide Navigation Menu Similar to FogBugz HomePage

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was looking for JavaScript library, which is able to provide navigation menu similar to

http://www.fogcreek.com/FogBugz/learnmore.html (left most navigation menu)

Any recommandation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have this **[jQuery accordion Plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-accordion/)**, and see a demo here **[jQuery accordion Plugin Demo](http://jquery.bassistance.de/accordion/demo/)**